How to find a duplicate value from a one column in SharePoint and update the latest duplicate column to new value using power automate
I have a SharePoint list were one column has duplicate values with same numbers .I need to query all the duplicate values from the SharePoint list for one column and update the item values which is duplicate and recently created .This i want to achieve using power automate.
enter image description here
First column has duplicate values which are created at same time .I need to get the latest duplicate value id and change the value

Get items

Select


sort(body('Select'),'sortby'))


Compose

range(0,length(outputs('Compose_2')))


Select 2

addProperty(
  outputs('Compose_2')?[item()],
  'IsDuplicate',
  if(
    equals(
    outputs('Compose_2')?[item()]?['concat'],
    outputs('Compose_2')?[sub(item(),1)]?['concat']),
    'T','F'
  )
)

this above action is returning result as T ,even for non duplicate items


can you provide sample data so we can reproduce your problem?

i have add the data in question now .

If null = null then T.
You've used Concat in your Select, but then you used concat in your if. It's case-sensitive.
Either change this to lower case "concat":

Or update this to Upper case:
addProperty(
  outputs('Compose_2')?[item()],
  'IsDuplicate',
  if(
    equals(
    outputs('Compose_2')?[item()]?['Concat'],
    outputs('Compose_2')?[sub(item(),1)]?['Concat']),
    'T','F'
  )
)


where should i make changes now

see above, updated answer
